# How to create a telegram poll with feedback using grammY

Tags: typescript, telegram-bot, deno, grammy

I am using Deno and GrammY to create a simple bot that will send a poll to the user on the `/q` command, and then when the user attempts the poll, would reply to the user on the basis of the choice that he took.

The code of the the `bot.ts` as of now looks like:

```
import { Bot } from "https://deno.land/x/grammy@v1.11.2/mod.ts";

const bot = new Bot(MY_REDACTED_BOT_TOKEN);

bot.command("q", async (ctx) => {
  ctx.api.sendPoll(
    ctx.msg.chat.id,
    `What is 1+1?`,
    ["0", "1", "2", "3"],
    {
      is_anonymous: false,
      type: "quiz",
      correct_option_id: 2,
    }
  );
});

bot.start();
```

How can I add the functionality to wait for the user to attempt the quiz and then proceed on the basis of it (something equivalent to [PollAnswerHandler](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.pollanswerhandler.html) in `python-telegram-bot`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for [`poll_answer`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) like shown below.
You will find all relevant information in the context object `ctx`, specifically under [`ctx.pollAnswer`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#pollanswer), e.g the `user` and the chosen `option_ids` (i.e selected answer(s)) as demonstrated in this code example:

```
const correctAnswerId = 2;

bot.command("q", async (ctx) => {
    const message = await ctx.api.sendPoll(
      ctx.msg.chat.id,
      `What is 1+1?`,
      ["0", "1", "2", "3"],
      {
        is_anonymous: false,
        type: "quiz",
        correct_option_id: correctAnswerId,
      }
    );
    console.log("sent poll #" + message.poll.id + " to user " + ctx.from?.id);
  });

bot.on('poll_answer', async (ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx.pollAnswer.user.first_name + " answered to poll " + ctx.pollAnswer.poll_id + " with option " + ctx.pollAnswer.option_ids) 

    if (ctx.pollAnswer.option_ids.indexOf(correctAnswerId) > -1 )  {
        await bot.api.sendMessage(ctx.pollAnswer.user.id, "You're a genius!");
    }
    else {
        await bot.api.sendMessage(ctx.pollAnswer.user.id, "Almost correct!");
    }
  });
```

In the code to send the poll I also added `const message =` to save the return value, which contains `message.poll.id`. This can be used to keep track of which poll was sent to which user so that you can easily find out to which poll a poll response refers. Note: the poll Id changes every time you send the poll.

The console would show for example:

> sent poll #5418284016237281795 to user 1234567890
> jps answered to poll 5418284016237281795 with option 2